# Angular5: REST API Service with pagnation, mapping of the objects

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I added pagnation to my REST API backend. No I have to change my angular services.

The api will now return jsons like the following:

```
{
    "count": 0,
    "next": null or url,
    "previous": null or url,
    "results": [..]
}
```

Before the changes it was just an array of objects.

This is my current service, which is of course not working anymore:

```
list(): Observable<StudentCourse[]> {
  let url = `${this.url}/student_courses/`;
  return this.httpClient.get<StudentCourse[]>(url, { headers: this.headers })
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('GET student-course', []))
    );
}
```

How can I map the `results` to the array of objects (`StudentCourse[]`) in the easiest way? And store the urls of `next` and `previous` in a variable directly in the service for later usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a JSON response page wrapper interface:

```
interface IPageResult<T> {
    count: number,
    next: string | null,
    previous: string | null,
    results: T[]
}
```

And then replace the raw arrays with it:

```
list(): Observable<IPageResult<StudentCourse>> {
  let url = `${this.url}/student_courses/`;
  return this.httpClient.get<IPageResult<StudentCourse>>(url, { headers: this.headers })
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('GET student-course', []))
    );
}
```

As for the `previous` and `next` values, you can just access them wherever you like - in the service or in the consumer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am newby with angluar. No I am gettinge the following error: `Type 'Observable<any[] | IPageResult<StudentCourse[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IPageResult<StudentCourse[]>>'`

Comment: Okay, I updated the example. You have to change the method return type as well (or you can omit it altogether since the compiler can guess it).

Comment: sry, still same error `Type 'Observable<any[] | IPageResult<StudentCourse>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IPageResult<StudentCourse>>'.
  Type 'any[] | IPageResult<StudentCourse>' is not assignable to type 'IPageResult<StudentCourse>'.
    Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'IPageResult<StudentCourse>'.
      Property 'count' is missing in type 'any[]'.
`

Comment: This is because the `catchError` pipe will return `this.handleError...` in case there is an error, and that's why the type of the function is `Observable<any[] | IPageResult<StudentCourse[]>>`. This means that it didn't work in your original example as well :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I changed your `interface` to a `class` and than its possible to pass `new PageResult<any>()` to my error function. Or do you ses any problems?